# Installing Windows in Ubuntu installed hard disk partition

Tags: windows

I was trying install windows on my Ubuntu laptop,I have only one disk partition on which i have istalled ubuntu,While trying to installing windows I got an error that "Windows cannot be installed in this drive,Windows supports only NTFS file system,How can I install windows in an ubuntu ext3 file system?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the GParted partition editor to shrink your Ubuntu partiton.
To install GParted, use...

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

[image]
Afterwards, install Windows in the free space you created.